# System Tray Balloon Notifications from Adobe Air?

Tags: windows, air, notifications, system-tray, popup-balloons

Is it possible to make an Adobe Air app create a native windows balloon notification/tooltip? I know it is possible to make a window appear in the corner, but I would like to use native windows notifications.